# SwiftUI: whole rounded edges for a rectangle

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a rectangle view which I want to round the whole right and left edges to produce a shape like this:

[image]

I've tried to do rounded corners for top left and bottom right using the following struct but to no avail:

```
struct RoundedCorner: Shape {
    var radius: CGFloat = .infinity
    var corners: UIRectCorner = .allCorners

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        return Path(path.cgPath)
    }
}

extension View {
    func cornerRadius(_ radius: CGFloat, corners: UIRectCorner) -> some View {
        clipShape( RoundedCorner(radius: radius, corners: corners) )
    }
}
```

is there a way to draw such shape ?

Comment: have you tried  ```var corners: UIRectCorner = [.bottomRight, .topLeft]``` ?

Comment: It does not fit your needs, see description of `cornerRadii` argument. You need rather a shape based on `Path.quadCurve` inside.